# SQL Sum Case Statement - group by case

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I'm simply trying to write an sql query to sum a group of fields.

I have 2 columns, one of which is Account Name, the other is Amount

I'd only like to sum two of the account names:

```
=sum(case when [Account Name] like Salaries or 'Other Income', Fields!Amount.Value)
```

the following works fine,

```
=sum(Fields!Amount.Value)
```

but I'm trying to narrow down the number of account names that are included in the sum.  I'm trying to figure out how to use a case statement then group by that case statement.

Comment: Can you post the entire query?

Comment: I switched the when to where, but when I 'okay' out of the expression window my data cell reads "<<Expr>>" and going to the Preview window indicates a general error.     =sum(case where [Account Name] like Salaries or 'Other Income', Fields!Amount.Value)

Comment: This doesn't look like SQL. Is that an Excel formula? Are you trying to translate to SQL?

Comment: That's all I've got.  I'm really just experimenting with this.  I've got two columns, one is Account Name, the other is Amount.  There are 12 Account Names.  I'd like to learn to combine more than one Account Name category, i.e. Salaries + Other Income = result

Comment: it's in visual studio... my sql is rudimentary, I'm much better at excel

Comment: rather, I'm trying to learn to do this in SQL / visual studio

Comment: What version of SQL is this?

Comment: Is this using SQL Server Reporting Services or Report Builder?  This is very different to using what most people call "SQL" or "Visual Studio"

Comment: I'm in Microsoft Visual Studio; In the solutions window, right click on Reports, add new item, select Report Project.  I believe it's part of SSDT

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark here because I think from your example that you're using SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS), and the syntax is quite different to T-SQL or ANSI SQL, which is what most people think of when you say "SQL".

If that's the case, and I have no experience with this so this may be completely wrong, I'm guessing you might need to try something using either `iif` or `switch` like this:

```
=sum(iif(Fields![Account Name].Value = 'Salaries' 
      or Fields![Account Name].Value = 'Other Income', Fields!Amount.Value, 0))
```